# If $p$ and $q = 2p + 1$ are both odd primes, show that $-4$ and $2(-1)^{(1/2)(p-1)}$ are both primitive roots modulo $q$.

Tags: group-theory, elementary-number-theory, primitive-roots

> If $p$ and $q = 2p + 1$ are both odd primes, show that $-4$ and $2(-1)^{(1/2)(p-1)}$ are both primitive roots modulo $q$.

I cannot get heads nor tails of how to even start this let alone finish it

Comment: What are the three mysterious characters?

Comment: Sorry Brian, I was struggling to correct some typing issues. Hope that clears it up

Comment: I’m afraid not: I see an unrecognized character before the $4$, before the $-1$ in the first parenthesis, and after the $p$ in the exponent.

Comment: I think that may have fixed that problem, supposed to be a negative four and its two time the (-1)

Comment: In that case the mysterious characters are apparently not supposed to print, and I’ve simply removed them; does it still look all right on your end?

Comment: Hello, welcome to Maths.SE.  Please ensure that your question is fully understandable without the title. The title's purpose is to attract people to your question (and to make it easily searchable). Once it has done that, it's job is done. The question should be self-contained.

Answer (score 2):

Recall that $q$ has $\varphi(\varphi(q))$ primitive roots, that is, $p-1$ primitive roots. Also, there are $p$ quadratic non-residues modulo $q$. Since every primitive root is a NR, *all but one* quadratic non-residue of $q$ is a primitive root of $q$. Which one?

The prime $q$ is of the form $4k+3$, and therefore $-1$ is a quadratic non-residue of $q$. It is clear that $-1$ is not a primitive root. So to prove that $a$ is a primitive root of $q$, it is enough to show that $a$ is a NR of $q$  not congruent to $-1$.

(i) The case $a=-4$:  Since $-1$ is a NR, and $4$ is clearly a QR, it follows that $-4$ is an NR. Since $-4$ is not congruent to $-1$ modulo $q$ ($q$ cannot be $3$),  it is a primitive root of $q$.

(ii) The case $a=(-1)^{(p-1)/2}(2)$: Here you will be using the fact that $2$ is a NR of a prime $q$ if and only if $q$ is congruent to $\pm 3$ modulo $8$. There are two cases to consider, $q$ of the form $8k+3$ and $q$ of the form $8k+7$.

**Remark:** We describe a more group-theoretic approach. The primitive roots of $q$ are the objects $a$ of full order $q-1=2p$. The order of any $a$ divides $2p$, so to show $a$ is a primitive root it is enough to show that $a$ does not have order $2$ or $p$. The only element of order $2$ is $-1$. If $a$ has order $p$, one can show that $x^2\equiv a\pmod{q}$ has a solution, that is, $a$ is a quadratic residue of $q$. So to show $a$ is a primitive root it is enough to show that $a$ is a quadratic non-residue not congruent to $-1$.

Answer (score 0):

Theorem: if $p$ is prime, $p\nmid a$ and for all prime divisors $q$ of $p-1$ we have $a^{(p-1)/q}\not\equiv 1\pmod{p}$, then $a$ is a primitive root mod $p$.

I'll prove three parts: If $p,q$ are odd primes and $q=2p+1$, then:

i) $-4$ is a primitive root mod $q$.

ii) if $p\equiv 1\pmod{4}$, then $2$ is a primitive root mod $q$.

iii) if $p\equiv 3\pmod{4}$, then $-2$ is a primitive root mod $q$.

i) We're left with proving $(-4)^2\not\equiv 1\pmod{q}$ and $(-4)^p\not\equiv 1\pmod{q}$.

The first one is clear, because $q>5$.

The second one is equivalent to $2^{2p}\not\equiv -1\pmod{q}$, i.e. $2^{q-1}\not\equiv -1\pmod{q}$, which is true by Fermat's Little theorem (and remember $q>5$).

ii) We want to prove that if $p\equiv 1\pmod{4}$, then $2^2\not\equiv 1\pmod{q}$ and $2^p\not\equiv 1\pmod{q}$.

The first one is clear, because $q>5$.

The second one is equivalent to $2^{(q-1)/2}\not\equiv 1\pmod{q}$. By [Euler's Criterion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_criterion) this is equivalent to $\left(\frac{2}{q}\right)\not\equiv 1\pmod{q}$.

By [Quadratic Reciprocity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_reciprocity#.C2.B12_and_the_second_supplement), this is true, because $q=2p+1=2(4k+1)+1=8k+3$.

iii) We want to prove that if $p\equiv 3\pmod{4}$, then $(-2)^2\not\equiv 1\pmod{q}$ and $(-2)^p\not\equiv 1\pmod{q}$.

The first one is clear, because $q>5$.

The second one is equivalent to $2^p\not\equiv -1\pmod{q}$, because $p$ is odd. This is equivalent to $2^{(q-1)/2}\not\equiv -1\pmod{q}$. By Euler's Criterion, this is equivalent to $\left(\frac{2}{q}\right)\not\equiv -1\pmod{q}$, which is true by Quadratic Reciprocity, because $q=2p+1=2(4k+3)+1=8k+7$.